# How to get wider view on orthographic camera?

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to catch a wider view of my model. I tried moving the camera back on y axis, but this seemed to do nothing. How can i come about this? [image]

In red is how much i would like to see on render.

Comment: There isn't any reason to move camera back in this case as it's orthographic. Change its scale, see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/how-can-i-get-a-cabinet-projection-camera and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98836/orthographic-view-with-something-like-shift-transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Orthographic camera scale of 4000 just to see the scene,
then your objects must be huge.

You can select all the objects in your scene and scale them down,
or crank that ortho scale up further, to say 5000.

Answer (score 6):

When using an orthographic camera the distance to the camera does not have any effect on the view.

Use **Orthographic Scale** to change the view instead.

[image]

The {Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/camera.html) illustrates the difference between perspective and orthographic cameras:

> Perspective:
>
> **Focal Length/Field of View** Control the field of view set by lens property or by angle as selected in the Lens Unit menu.

[image]

> **Orthographic Scale**
>
> Controls the size of objects projected on the image.

[image]

More info in this link:

## [What are the differences between Orthographic and Perspective views?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/648/what-are-the-differences-between-orthographic-and-perspective-views)

Answer (score 1):

if you switch the camera type to "perspective" rather that "orthographic" in the camera menu, you can move the camera back on the y-axis and it will appear to zoom out. The reason orthographic dosen't do that is because it dosen't scale things depending on how far away they are.

Answer (score 0):

RMB to select the camera frame, click G and twice Z,then move your cursor up and down your screen to zoom in or out.

Comment: This doesn't work with an orthographic camera.